# sed to delete lines using multiple search string

Tags: sed

I have a text file, let say `test1.txt`, I need to remove the line containing dog and date with `"29-APR-2015"`

Using the below command to accomplish it but it is not deleting the lines.

Where as if i mention just with `/DOG/d` it is deleting the lines containing `DOG`.

**command file (sedcommands)**

```
/DOG,29-APR-2015/d
```

**test1.txt**

```
DOG          29-APR-2015          
DOG          29-APR-2015          
DOG          30-APR-2015          
CAT          29-APR-2015          
CAT          29-APR-2015
```

**command**

```
sed -f sedcommands test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/DOG/{/29-APR-2015/d}' test1
```

This method allows for any order. ie. `DOG` can either be before or after the date.

Comment: @cuonglm - `sed --posix '/DOG/{/29-APR-2015/d}'` works fine in GNU sed version 4.2.1 (with all GNU extensions disabled).

Comment: @Peter.O: No, POSIX require terminator between the command anh `}`. At least your command won't work in BSD sed.

Comment: @Peter.O, GNU `sed`'s `--posix` is to tell it to be _more_ POSIX conformant. It's not telling it to report an error on any non-POSIX code you throw at it. It would not make GNU `sed` more POSIX conformant  to report an error when you give it that non-standard `{xxx}` code.

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
sed -e '/DOG/!b' -e '/29-APR-2015/!b' -e d file
```

`b`ranch to the end if you don't provide any label.

or:

```
sed '/DOG/{/29-APR-2015/d
}' file
```

Modern `sed` implementations also support `{command;}` form, this's an accepted extension by POSIX, but not required:

```
sed '/DOG/{/29-APR-2015/d;}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`/DOG,29-APR-2015/d` will not work because there is no comma between `DOG` and `9-APR-2015`.  Try this;

```
$ sed -e '/DOG[[:space:]]*29-APR-2015/d' test1.txt 
     DOG          30-APR-2015          
     CAT          29-APR-2015          
     CAT          29-APR-2015
```

`[[:space:]]*` allows for zero or more white space characters between `DOG` and `9-APR-2015`.  The character class `[:space:]` allows both ordinary spaces and tabs and is safe to use with unicode fonts.

Answer (score 1):

The command file should contain:

```
/DOG *29-APR-2015/d
```

That is, `DOG` followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by specified date.