# What the equivalent of "grep | cut" using sed or awk?

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cat, cut

Say I had a config file `/etc/emails.conf`

```
email1 = user@dinkum.dorg 
email2 = user@winkum.worg
email3 = user@stinkum.storg
```

and I wanted to get email2

I could do a:

```
grep email2 /etc/emails.conf | cut -d'=' -f2
```

to get the email2, but how do I do it "cooler" with one sed or awk command and remove the whitespace that the cut command would leave?

Comment: You can remove the first `cat`: `grep email2 /etc/emails.conf | ...`

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós dang, I had thought I tried that but it failed for some completely unknown hidden reason (because obviously it should have worked).  I just put the file name at the end of the cut wrongly and that's why it didn't work.   I revised the question, I don't think it invalidates the answers.

Comment: I really don't understand your question: you already have the string that you're searching for: `result="email2"` -- what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using awk?

```
awk -F = '/email2/ { print $2}' /etc/emails.conf
```

- `-F =` Fields are separated by '='
- `'/email2/ { print $2}'` On lines that match "email2", print the second field

Comment: can it trim the leading space too?

Comment: @PeterTurner, my version of `awk` permits `-F ' *= *'`, which is a wildcarded expression that groups spaces either side of `=` as part of the separator.

Answer (score 4):

The *exact* equivalent would be something like:

```
sed -n '/email2/{s/^[^=]*=\([^=]*\).*/\1/;p;}' < file
```

But you'd probably want instead:

```
sed -n 's/^[^=]*email2[^=]*=[[:blank:]]*//p' < file
```

(that is match `email2` only on the part before the first `=` and return everything on the right of the first `=` (skipping leading blanks), not only the part up to the second `=` if any).

Comment: Is space required between `{ s`?

Comment: @cuonglm, no. AFAICT, `;}` above is not POSIX but I don't know of any modern `sed` implementation where that fails.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly I have stucked when working with [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199284/38906). After re-reading POSIX sed documentation, I see `;}` is an accepted extension, but it's not required. It's strange that GNU sed with `--posix` option still allow [{command}](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199284/38906) form. Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: @cuonglm `{command}` is not required to report an error by POSIX. It's just that a POSIX _script_ must not use it as the behaviour is not specified there. Where GNU `sed` is not conformant even with `--posix` is that it doesn't accept `;` in label names.

Comment: is it preferable to us "<" vs just using the file as the argument (I'm putting this into a bash script)?

Comment: @PeterTurner, see [When should I use input redirection?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756).

Comment: I can't find where `;}` is mentioned in the [Sed POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) as an accepted extension.  It seems to be required by `The <right-brace> shall be preceded by a <newline> or <semicolon>`.  @cuonglm or Stephane, could you clarify?

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, `;}` is not POSIX, that what Stephane said in his comment above. But I remember it will be in next POSIX version, there's an issue in austin bug group.

Comment: @cuonglm, no, I mean I don't see it as *just* an extension.  "The right brace shall be preceded by a newline or semicolon...."  So if you precede it with a semicolon in your Sed script, haven't you followed the explicit instructions of POSIX?

Comment: @cuonglm, huh, I still don't see it in the specs.  But if it will be changed in the next POSIX edition I suppose it's not critical.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard: The austinbug group link http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=961

Comment: @Wildcard Ops, look like the spec was changed follow that issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47858/discussion-between-wildcard-and-cuonglm).

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does little to explain *why* the command works. I've posted an alternative `sed` answer with that explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nlE 's/email2\s*=\s*// and say'    file
```

Where:

- `perl -nl`  is a for each line do...
- `s/email2 = //`  removes the searched email id and if you could do it ...
- `say` prints the current input input line
- `\s*` zero or more spaces (equivalent to [ \t\n]*)

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for golfing, but where I'm running this (some sort of stripped down Cisco appliance), I'm not sure I'm going to have perl, especially the version of perl that has `say`.

Comment: perl 5.10 appeared 7 year ago but sometimes we don't have it... `perl -nle 's/email2\s*=\s*// and  print'`

Answer (score 2):

To get something like `grep | cut` you can use `sed -n s/A/B/p`.

By default, `sed` prints every line after all commands are processed. You can silence all output that you don't explicitly print from a command with `sed -n`.

The `s` command takes the form `s/$FIND/$REPLACE/$FLAGS`. Specifically, the `p` flag prints the line whenever a replacement is made.

With these combined, you can easily match and cut:

```
sed -nE "s/email2 = (.+)/\1/p" < /etc/emails.conf
```

In fact, this is strictly more powerful than `grep | cut` because you can use an arbitrary replacement pattern.

(The `-E` option enables modern regex, which allows you to reference capture groups in the replacement pattern. For a simple cut, you can get away without it by using more clever patterns.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the field separator to any special value such as "=".
By default, AWK uses contiguous spaces and tabs as field separators, which are skipped, so it will interpret each line of your file as having three fields, without any leading space on field three

```
awk '/^email2/ { print $3 }'
```

produces

```
user@winkum.worg
```

The above would also match any lines starting with `email2`, such as `email20`, for exact match you can use

```
awk '$1 == "email2" { print $3 }'
```